# If P is the total of points on the plane. Find all functions $f:P\rightarrow P$, which fullfil some conditions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, problem-solving, intuition

If P is the total of points on the plane. Find all functions $f:P\rightarrow P$ such that for every two points $A, B$ of $P$, the points $A, B, f(A), f(B)$ are either collinear or con-cyclic.

I attempted to do it in the following way:

I state $S=(A:f(a)\ne A)$. Then for every three different points $X,Y,Z$ we will write $C(X,Y,Z)$ for the one radius circle or the line which passes through these points.

Afterwards I started taking cases like:

If $S$ is empty, then $f$ is an identity function.

If $|S|=1$, then $f$ is an identity function, in all places apart from one point.

I did not know how to continue it from here on, but I believe that this method is extremely tedious. Could you please explain to me an intuitive solution?

Comment: You don't say whether $f$ is bijective. What about projection onto a line? Then the entire image is a single line.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with group theory.

Comment: This problem on the Functional Equations Online Olympiad shortlist, and some solutions can be found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h2129233p15548037). The solutions all seem to be rather tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be points and $T$ a set of points with $A\notin T$. Define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}B&x=A\\A&x\in T\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ has the desired property because four pints $x,y,f(x),f(y)$ are actually just three points.

Or pick any circle-or-line (or CoL for short) and define $f$ as any map of this CoL to itself while being the identity outside that CoL. Then such $f$ also has this property.

Assume there is $f$ not matching the above. Then we can find two non-fixpoints $A,B$  points such that $A,B,f(A),f(B)$ are four distinct points and are on a unique CoL. We also know that there is another non- fixpoint $C$ not on That COL. Then the CoL through $A,C,f(A)$ and the CoL through $B,C,f(B)$ intersect exactly in $C$ and $f(C)$.

This is not complete yet, but I suspect that one cannot have many non- fuxpoints in such constellations.